# Merging Java objects and skipping nulls in java 7

Tags: java, xml, csv, xsd, jaxb

I have a program that takes a flat csv file and using xsd, maps the content out to an XML document.

I currently have a process that looks like this

```
// A0797 and children as list
A0797 a0797Items = o.createELIXPRODUCTSCOREPRODUCTA0797();
a0797Items.setA0069(line[25]);
a0797Items.setA0070(line[26]);
if (line[27].length() > 0)
{
a0797Items.setA0074(new BigInteger(line[27]));
}
if (line[28].length() > 0)
{
a0797Items.setA0073(new BigInteger(line[28]));
}
a0797Items.setA0071(line[29]);
prd.getA0797().add(a0797Items);
```

Columns 25, 26, etc. are mapped to the XML document. The business are now sending through additional data in the csv file, columns 33-37. These also need to be set in A0069, A0074 and A0074.

I can easily pull back the objects, bust was wondering how best I can merge them onto one line in the above script.

For example, today, section A0069 will take the data from the CSV file, and create:

```
<A0069>50</A0069>
```

With the extra data in the file, it now needs to generate like this

```
<A0069>20,30,50</A0069>
```

In some cases, you might just have 20 and 50, or 20 and 50 etc. etc.

What would be the best way to merge these and skip null values?

If one of the values were missing (say, 20), this would be bad:

```
<A0069>,30,50</A0069>
```

Ideally, I'd want this:

```
<A0069>30,50</A0069>
```

**Update 13/08/2015:**

Because I need to use Java 7, I've gone with this approach so far:

```
StringBuilder tUnitSB = new StringBuilder();
if (line[25] != null) tUnitSB.append(line[25]);
if (line[33] != null) tUnitSB.append(line[33]);
if (line[36] != null) tUnitSB.append(line[36]);
// Display results.
String tradeUnits = tUnitSB.toString();
a0797Items.setA0069(tradeUnits);
```

What I can't work out, is how to now comma separate them, without additonal commas creeping in.

Comment: Have you tried `String.join` ?

Comment: `String.join` is Java 8 only isn't it? I sadly need to make it work in Java 7